# How do I turn a GeoTIFF file into a bmp file?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, c++

I need to get GeoTIFF files transformed into bmp files so that I can display them as apart of some software that I am working on. Unfortunately, I am a total newbie with GIS and really don't know much about geography. I am working in C++ and need to have this included in what I am doing. A dll file would be great, although it is my understanding that we might need to include the source code from which the dll is created. I am wide open to any other technique that could be used as well. Can anyone help me with this?

I should also note that I am working on a Windows machine.

Comment: Working with TIFF Images C++ - http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/otherformats/article.php/c4933

Answer (score 3):

For converting from GeoTiff to BMP you can use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) library. It has C++ API and well-documented.

I have found GDAL convertion [example](http://thedaintydelegate.com/gdal/convert-geotiff-tiff-jpg-png-mrsid-to-jp2-in-c-using-gdal-tutorial/135/) for C#. I hope it will help you to start from.

For BMP you will need to create "world file" to store GeoReferencing information. I think GDAL will create it by default.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the answer.  I have also heard that there is something called Openev inside GDAL. My problem is figuring out how to turn GDAL or the relevant part of it into a dll or to be used some way as an API so that I can pass it in a geotiff file and getting a bmp file out of it to display.  The displaying of the bmp file is no problem.  All help is very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I've just recently learnt how to use gdal from a command line using pre-built libraries found on the gdal site.

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Dunno if this answers your question or not but I was able to strip the alpha from a tiff tile and re-save it, could possibly envoke a cmd prompt and wait for it to finish?

```
gdal_translate -of BMP your.tiff your.bmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use libtiff directly:  http://www.libtiff.org/ or use gdal. In reply to your comment on alex his answer: for gdal search for the gdal1x.dll (with x the version number), it is the only file you will need, apart from the header files of the same build. I usually find it easier to compile gdal myself to be sure I have the right header files.

For libtiff, it is best to build it yourself from source using the cvs version. In that case you will also have support for eg bigtiffs (larger than 4Gb).

Answer (score 1):

Try [MyGeodata GIS data online converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu) - it allows you to convert your GeoTIFF to the BMP format or other various formats. Run raster converter. This tool uses the GDAL library.

Answer (score 1):

See `gdal_translate`'s source code. It's in the GDAL source package available from from [this link](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource).