# Changing Dataset Property

Tags: gdal, convert, c++, image

I 'm working on GDAL C++. But I have some trouble to change GDALDataset property. I have converted "jpg" to "bmp" an image. But I want to do read an image(jpg) to gdaldataset then change dataset properties(gdaldataset) to "bmp". But I don't want to create a ".bmp" file any pc storage. Only change Gdaldataset properties to ("bmp").

Answer (score 1):

When working with GDAL through its C++ API, you communicate with the inner raster representation, which is independent from whether you are reading a `JPEG` or a `BMP` file, because input / output management is decoupled by using so called format drivers. It is an applied design pattern to separate the data representation layer (`GDALDataset`, `GDALRasterBand`) from the persistence layer (`GDALDriver`).